# 24 hour assignment rule

Tags: workflow

If nothing happens on the status after 24 hours, the lead should be reassigned to the Telesales Director and my workflow rule criteria is
NOT( ISCHANGED( Status ) )    =
DATEVALUE(( TODAY() ) + 24)
Please help me because I am having an error

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please include the error you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it now to this Likely_Decision_Date__c < TODAY() && IsConverted = False and created a time based workflow. Now my only problem is how can I assign the lead on a specific role/user if no changes has been made after 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

That's not how scheduled actions work. You cannot represent a scheduled action as part of your entry criteria in any type of declarative automation. Presumably the error is that this formula is invalid.

Here's the [relevant documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5) for Workflow Rules. You would need to capture the date of each status change to a field, and use a time-dependent action set to execute 24 hours after the date stored in that field. Time-dependent actions must be scheduled for execution *relative to a specific date field value*.

Note also that Workflow Rules are the oldest and least-capable of the declarative automation tools. It is highly recommended that you utilize Flow instead.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it now to this  

Likely_Decision_Date__c < TODAY() &&
IsConverted = False

and created a time based workflow.
Now my only problem is how can I assign the lead on  a specific role/user if no changes has been made after 24 hours

Comment: That should be the action in your time-dependent action.

Comment: `use Flow instead` - that would be record-triggered flows with scheduled paths, no?

Comment: I think so, yeah. I'm not as much of a Flow expert.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom  Date/Datetime field called "Last Status update Date". Don't expose this field on page layout, to be used for processing only.
2. First WF:  When lead record is created or edited, update the Last Status Update Date with current date or Datetime. Conditon for field update is - ISCHANGED (Status) OR isNEW(), To handle record create scenario.
3. 2nd WF for lead reassignment. This will trigger a time dependent action  and will fire on Last Status Update Date + 1 day and reassign the lead.
4. Mind Time Dependent Actions can be run on 2 scenarios only - when record is created And when record is created and edited and did not meet specified criteria. set the second one and make your filter condition as  TODAY() - Last Status Update Date  > 1
5. Instead of WF, try the same with Process Builder as that is more powerful declarative option.

Comment: That will work. Youre so helpful. Thank you